# How to rearrange badly input data in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that is arranged very badly [found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzFvg.png), and I would like to put it into long format for R for analyses. Specifically, I would like the data to be arranged in several different columns (family, trap type,date, count,etc.) Could anyone point me towards relevant literature for reshuffling this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful because we can't copy/paste the data.

Comment: @MrFlick I totally agree. I am new to the site. Is there a way to display a csv, or xlsx in my question?

Comment: MrFlick shared a relevant link to you, just follow the guide and all are happy.